# How to write tensorboard events files without installing / importing TF or PyTorch?

Tags: tensorboard, jax

Obviously events-file logging is included with TensorFlow and apparently there's an implementation included with PyTorch, but is there an officially supported standalone implementation of something like `SummaryWriter` for use outside of these two frameworks (e.g. if one is using JAX and doesn't want to also install/import TensorFlow or PyTorch)?

The `flax` library apparently has `flax.metrics.tensorboard`, but it just imports TensorFlow and implements a `SummaryWriter` using `tf.summary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorboardX might be helpful:
https://tensorboardx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tensorboard.html#

It does not require installing Tensorflow/Pytorch, but does require installation of the above, a much lighter-weight, library.